# Check In at Changi Airport Transfer Desk with Separate Itinerary Ticket / Dual Nationality / Different Names

Tags: dual-nationality, singapore-airlines

Does anyone have experience checking in at a Singapore Airlines transfer desk within Changi Airport, where the flight ticket for the second leg was separately booked using a different passport/name (dual nationality)?

Both tickets would use the same airline (Singapore Airlines), there would not be any checked baggage.

From the Changi Airport [website](http://www.changiairport.com/en/passenger-guide/transit.html?tabParent=Preflightcheck&anchor=flight-transfer), it appears to be possible to check in without having to exit immigration. However they also mention various cases where it is not possible (budget carrier, different carriers & bags not checked through, etc).
So, just to be sure, I would like to know if others have done this before without any problems?

Thanks

Comment: @MichaelHampton The OP there was advised to ask a different question with specifics of the airport and airlines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Singapore Airlines has multiple transfer desks within the terminals that they fly to/from (Terminal 2/3), and these terminals are connected air-side.

You will not have any trouble accessing these desks, and I would not expect them to have any need to see details of your inbound flight (I used one of them about 2 weeks ago and they certainly didn't care about my inbound).

Your potential issue, depending on your nationality, is that if you would need a visa to enter Singapore you will probably need to show details of your connecting flight when you check-in for your first flight so that they know you are only connecting in Singapore.  Even if you don't need a visa, they may ask for this in order to check that you have a ticket to leave Singapore at the end of your stay.  The fact you are using a different passport will not cause any issues here, but the fact you are using a different name may cause some confusion.